# How to upload files using Nuxt 3 features

Tags: upload, vuejs3, nuxt3

Looking for general instructions on file uploads from Nuxt experts. I need to create a file upload functionality in a Nuxt 3 app. Is there a particular Nuxt 3 approach to file uploads that I should know about? All tutorials offer multer, formidable or other similar libraries. However, Nuxt 3 has it's own Storage functionality. Can it be used for uploads, for example?